# Codename one - checkbox option in overflow menu

Tags: checkbox, menu, overflow, codenameone

I have a form with a basic overflow menu, that is supposed to offer options of manipulating a list of items of that form. One part is sorting the list by various means (which works well), the other part is providing a filtering of the list. E.g. having a simple shopping list of items that can be checked and I want the filter to show only "open" items, yet unchecked to focus on.

Can I add a previously assembled component to the overflow menu? Its just a dialog spawning in that location, so it should be able to house any component for that matter. However, the options "add(Material)CommandToOverflowMenu" only allow to add commands directly or a string, icon, listener combination.

If a custom component is not possible, I could still use the icon to show an empty checkbox first, and then update to an checked checkbox icon, once pressed. However, how to manipulate an existing overflow item, after it was added? I dont even see a way to remove previously added overflow items, as the "getOverflowCommands" returns an Iterable, which is not supposed to be used for manipulation of the list.

Is there a way to do this, I do I have to setup my own, custom, overflow menu like dialog?

Thanks and best regards

EDIT WITH SOLUTION
I created a new class to solve my problem:

```
public class ToggleCommand extends Command {

    private boolean selected;

    private static Image selectedImage = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_RADIO_BUTTON_CHECKED,
            new Label().getUnselectedStyle());
    private static Image unSelectedImage = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_RADIO_BUTTON_UNCHECKED,
            new Label().getUnselectedStyle());

    public ToggleCommand(String command) {
        this(command, selectedImage);
    }

    public ToggleCommand(String command, Image icon) {
        super(command, icon);
        selected = true;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
        if (selected) {
            this.setIcon(selectedImage);
        } else {
            this.setIcon(unSelectedImage);
        }
    }
}
```

which you can use like this:

```
filterDoneCommand = new ToggleCommand("Show closed?") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            filterDoneCommand.setSelected(!filterDoneCommand.isSelected());
            // do your other stuff
        }
    };
    getToolbar().addCommandToOverflowMenu(filterDoneCommand);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overflow menu wasn't built well and should probably be rewritten. We don't have builtin support for checkbox options there and making a change to add it would be pretty cumbersome.

The best workaround I can think of is to add a command with a checkbox as an icon. Then checking/unchecking when the command is invoked. The `addMaterialCommandToOverflowMenu` and similar command methods return a `Command` instance which you need to save for future reference in this case.

If you want to go "all out" you can just add a button to the right side toolbar and use that to show a completely customized overflow menu. That might be easier in some regards.

Comment: I tried the following code snipped, which one could expect to work:
 

`Command cmd = getToolbar().addCommandToOverflowMenu("My Command", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_RADIO_BUTTON_UNCHECKED, new Button().getUnselectedStyle()), (ev) -> {
   cmd.setIcon(FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_RADIO_BUTTON_CHECKED, new Button().getUnselectedStyle()));
 
});`



however, I am getting a compiler error reading "the local variable cmd may not have been initialized". But I cannot initialize it in any other way, as it has to be final. Can this be solved?

Comment: You need to define cmd in the class level not in the method level